# Parsing inner tags using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, parsing, internationalization, nokogiri

I'm stuck not being able to parse irregularly embedded html tags. Is there a way to remove all html tags from a node and retain all text?

I'm using the code:

```
rows = doc.search('//table[@id="table_1"]/tbody/tr')

details = rows.collect do |row|
  detail = {}
  [
    [:word, 'td[1]/text()'],
    [:meaning, 'td[6]/font'],
  ].collect do |name, xpath|
      detail[name] = row.at_xpath(xpath).to_s.strip
    end
  detail
end
```

Using Xpath:

```
[:meaning, 'td[6]/font']
```

generates

```
:meaning: ! '<font size="3">asking for information specifying <font
    color="#CC0000" size="3">what is your name?</font> /what/ as in, <font color="#CC0000" size="3">I'm not sure what you mean</font>
    /what/ as in <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="http://somesecretlink.com">what</a></font>
```

On the other hand, using Xpath:

```
'td/font/text()'
```

generates

```
:meaning: asking for information specifying
```

thus ignoring all children of the node. What I want to achieve is this

```
:meaning: asking for information specifying what is your name? /what/ as in, I'm not sure what you mean /what/ as in what? I can't hear you
```

Comment: I don't see where's the first font tag is closed. Have you tried at('td/font').text ?

Comment: Roman, I corrected the output. It does generate closing font tag.

Comment: Ok, did you try to do row.at_xpath('td[6]/font').text ?

Comment: Thank you Roman. You caught it right - .text was one of the component in coming at the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on what you need to extract. If you want all text in font elements, you can do it with the following xpath:

```
'td/font//text()'
```

It extracts all text nodes in font tags. If you want *all* text nodes in the cell, then:

```
'td//text()'
```

You can also call the `text` method on a Nokogiri node:

```
row.at_xpath(xpath).text
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. `.text` was throwing error at first, as the first parsed row was empty. I did `rows.each_with_index.collect ` instead of `rows.collect` and skipped the first row. And ta-da! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I added an answer for this same sort of question the other day. It's a very easy process.

Take a look at: [Convert HTML to plain text and maintain structure/formatting, with ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073523/convert-html-to-plain-text-and-maintain-structure-formatting-with-ruby/6074774#6074774)